# ,htaccess Configuration Meaning

Tags: .htaccess, magento, configuration

```
############################################
## new my account page redirect

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/customer/account/logout/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/loginPost/
RewriteRule ^customer/account/ https://www.website.com/customer/site_account [R=301,L]
```

- I am curious to know what does the above configuration mean in
  .htaccess file ?
- What does it direct or do in my magento application ?
- I have updated the question & added "RewriteRule". Actually i have a href with href="/customer/account/logout/" when i click on href it requests "POST" request. and when i open the same link in URL(another tab) it shows "GET" request. So, the thing i am trying to get from the above question is i doubt if the above configuration in .htaccess (mentioned in question) making the POST request on href instead of GET.

I have not find valid info on search results.

Feel free to share thoughts.
Thankyou.

Comment: First of all thanks for showing your efforts in your question, keep it up. IMHO your htaccess file doesn't look correct to me, it only has RewriteCond(conditions) but NO RewriteRule so I don't think it may be rewriting or redirecting any url. If you have question how you could rewrite or redirect urls(infernally or externally) then please do mention all details in your question.

Comment: Thankyou for the response, i have updated the question & added "RewriteRule". Actually i have a href with href="/customer/account/logout/" when i click on href it requests "POST" request. and when i open the same link in URL(another tab) it shows "GET" request.  So, the thing i am trying to get from the above question is i doubt if the above configuration in .htaccess (mentioned in question) making the POST request on href instead of GET. Please do share your thoughts on this. Thankyou

Comment: Sorry but this is still not clear, if you could add details in your question. Like from which url to which url you want to redirect or rewrite then it will be helpful, but please update this in your question only as comments are not meant for this, thank you and happy learning :)

Answer (score 2):

This is your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/customer/account/logout/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/loginPost/
RewriteRule ^customer/account/ https://www.website.com/customer/site_account [R=301,L]
```

This can never make any `POST` request but might be happening here is this scenario:

1. Browser sends a `POST` request to URI `/customer/account/logout/`
2. That request skips this rule first time due to your first `RewriteCond`
3. Another rule in this .htaccess (since this is Magento) rewrites every non-file, non-directory to `index.php`
4. `mod_rewrite` loops again and second time this rule redirect since `REQUEST_URI` has become `/index.php` now.
5. This rule now redirects with a `GET` request from browser.

You should make 2 adjustments in this rule:

1. Skip this redirect for `POST` requests
2. Match `THE_REQUEST` (original request) instead of modifiable `REQUEST_URI`.

Suggested rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/(customer/account/logout|loginPost)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^customer/account/ /customer/site_account [R=301,L,NC]
```

PS: Before testing make sure to clear your browser cache.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer, can i make the request of this as "GET" customer/account/logout|loginPost ?

Comment: 5. This rule now redirects with a GET request from browser.  That's not happening actually it has POST request.

Comment: Actually i have a href with href="/customer/account/logout/" when i click on href it requests "POST" request. and when i open the same link in URL(another tab) it shows "GET" request.  I am not sure what configuration causes the "/customer/account/logout/" api call as "POST" .

Comment: `when i click on href it requests "POST" request`: This is happening in your code. Either Javascript or backend

Comment: i want to know the reason why /customer/account/logout/ on a href, it uses POST request instead of GET.

Comment: Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.

Comment: What should i check into "301/302 redirect URL" ?

Comment: I have written clearly that you need to check each and every URL that gets redirected with 301/302. What are source and target URLs?